# Validate shipping address using fedex API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fedex

I am using `rails 2.3.17`, I have used `fedex` .

How can I validate the shipping address using fedex?
Is there any proper documentation for the fedex api to validate address?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have used the plugin https://github.com/kdonovan/fedex

Please have a look on it

Answer (score 2):

Honestly don't use FedEx's API to do address resi/comm versification. Its fraught with error, I've actually fed it FedEx owned warehouse locations and it told me they were residential.  It may cost money but its better to use a third party like a [smartystreets.com](http://smartystreets.com) or someone like that.

If you have a set of fedex creds you can visit http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/ and get the API guides etc. I will say that some of their API's have errors in them so depending on what you're trying to do you can get some interesting results.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the [fedex gem](https://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex).

You can find this example of address validation in [the docs](https://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex#-verifying-an-address-):

```
address = {
  :address     => "5 Elm Street",
  :city        => "Norwalk",
  :state       => "CT",
  :postal_code => "06850",
  :country     => "USA"
}

address_result = fedex.validate_address(:address => address)

address_result.residential
# => true

address_result.score
# => 100

address_result.postal_code
# => "06850-3901"
```

Comment: No actually I am using a old plugin, it does not have any validate_address method, rather it has some end point url pointing to certain databases.

Comment: Please add some more information to your question about the gems/plugins you are using.

Comment: Please check the editted question and check the plugin.